# Consequences of using computed variables vs useState/useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

If I have a variable whose value can be fully derived based on the value of another property, is there any consequence/pitfall to initializing a computed variable vs using a combination of `useState`/`useEffect` to track the variable? Let me illustrate with a contrived example:

```js
/**
 * ex paymentAmounts: [100, 300, 400]
 */
const Option1 = ({paymentAmounts}) => {
  const [average, setAverage] = useState(paymentAmounts.reduce((acc, curr) => curr + acc, 0) / paymentAmounts.length)

  useEffect(() => {
    setAverage(paymentAmounts.reduce((acc, curr) => curr + acc, 0) / paymentAmounts.length)
  }, [paymentAmounts])

  return (
    <div>
      Average: {average}
    </div>
  )
}
```

or more simply

```js
/**
 * ex paymentAmounts: [100, 300, 400]
 */
const Option2 = ({paymentAmounts}) => {
  const average = paymentAmounts.reduce((acc, curr) => curr + acc, 0) / paymentAmounts.length

  return (
    <div>
      Average: {average}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Am I giving up any control and/or React benefits by using Option2?

Vue.js seems to have this option via [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties).

Comment: There is no need of "useState", "useEffect" in your example. You do not have any place where you update value of `average` in your component. You can definitely use `Option2` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use state (as in `useState` that is) when you want to track something **in** your component (or share it between its children) **between rerenders**. In your case, you're getting this "state" from your parent component (the parent is the actual state holder). Every change in the parent state (`paymentAmounts` in your situation) will reflect in your child component automatically.

As a general "rule", don't use state for data that can be calculated. Keep in mind that every change of a state tracked variable will force the component to re-render. Another bad usage example is this:

```
const Example = ({variable1}) => {
  const [variable, setVariable] = useState(variable1);

  ...
}
```

A couple of additional notes:

1. In your first solution you introduce an additional overhead by using
   `useEffect`. As pointed out already, your child component will
   always re-render and recalculate the `average` when your parent's
   state change.
2. You're using `setAverage` wrong in your `useEffect` hook. The setter
   takes either a new value or a function that accepts the current one
   and returns the new one.
3. Not sure what you expect from the `paymentAmounts / paymentAmounts.length` calculation. I suppose it is just a dummy
   code, but if not, look into it. You're dividing the array itself (not the sum of its values) by its length.

So, in short - Yes, you should be using a simple variable to calculate the average and ditch the `useState`/`useEffect`. Not only you're **NOT** giving up any benefits, you're actually making your code more performant, maintainable, readable and error-free.

Answer (score 2):

The only reason to use hooks or other state tracking functionality is if you plan on changing the state within the component itself. From the example you gave, that is not the case. If the prop `paymentAmounts` is updated the component will get updated by React and so will your computed constant, `average`.

So, you get no benefit from using useState & useEffect here. Keep it simple with your computed constant!

Answer (score 1):

Let's analyze the `Option1` component step-by-step:

```
/**
 * ex paymentAmounts: [100, 300, 400]
 */
const Option1 = ({paymentAmounts}) => {

  //1
  const [average, setAverage] = useState(paymentAmounts / paymentAmounts.length)

  //2
  useEffect(() => {
   setAverage(paymentAmounts.reduce((acc, curr) => curr + acc, 0) / paymentAmounts.length)
  }, [ paymentAmounts])

  return (
    <div>
      Average: {average}
    </div>
  )
}
```

1. Here you are initializing the `average` state variable from the `paymentAmounts` prop. During the initial render, the initial value of the `average` state variable would be calculated from it. So far so good.
2. In the `useEffect` you are adding a dependency on the `paymentAmounts` array from the prop. The effect callback will run when a new array instance is passed as a prop and also on the initial render. So here is the catch, the effect callback won't run when you push new numbers in the existing array reference, it will only run when you pass a new array instance in the prop having the updated numbers.
   So you may see no change in the `average` if you simply do `paymentAmounts.push(400)` in `Option1`'s parent component.

So for all use cases `Option2` is the best way to achieve what you wanted to do. There is no need to introduce a state in this functional component. The value in the UI can be derived from the `props` itself.

Comment: I mostly agree with everything you say here except your example `paymentAmounts.push(400)`. If `paymentAmounts` is tracked state then you should never mutate it in the parent like this. Instead I'd do something like `setPaymentAmounts([...paymentAmounts, 400])` in the parent -- which would trigger the appropriate dependency update in the child.

Comment: @coloradocolby yes that is exactly my point, in your comment you are sending a new instance of an array by copying the elements of the old one which will trigger a re-render. On the otherhand a mutation will not, just clarifying it.